# Hold review revisit?

Tags: discussion, flagging

A few days ago I posted a question which was marked as too broad: [the question in question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/what-if-humans-generate-a-sentience-suppressing-field?)

I've made substantial changes, including explicitly stating criteria, narrowing the scope to one based on a single invention, and adding some details. If you want to get a quick overview of the changes, then your best bet would be to look at version 1, 4, and 9.

I cannot check the review queue, so I don't know if it's on the queue, and I don't think that this is a case for direct moderator intervention (the only flag option I have for the question). I directed a comment (which I've just deleted, since it would be spammy to ask the same question in multiple places) at the person who initially flagged it as too broad, hoping to either get more feedback or start the process of removing the hold, but I haven't heard anything since then and have decided to take my question here. (I made the comment a day ago, if you are wondering about the timing.)

Is the question still too broad? If it is, do you have any suggestions for narrowing it? If not, can it get flagged for re-opening?

Comment: Surprisingly, I cannot see your question in review queue. But I am able to cast reopen vote. Will read your question and either vote for reopen or post as answer what I think needs to be done

Comment: For your info: I did cast a reopen vote. So it is in review queue

Comment: I await the judgement of the counsel, metaphorically speaking